# XmlDocument.Load() throws XmlSchemaValidationException

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm trying to validate an XML document against a schema (which is embedded in my program as a resource). I got everything to work, so I tried to test for errors by adding a second sibling node in the XML at a location where the schema specifies `maxOccurs="1"`. The problem is that my `ValidationEventHandler` is never getting called, also `XmlDocument.Load()` is throwing an `XmlSchemaValidationException` exception when I'd expected `XmlDocument.Validate()` to do that.

This is the code I have:

```
private void ValidateUserData( string xmlPath )
{
  var resInfo = Application.GetResourceStream( new Uri( @"MySchema.xsd", 
                   UriKind.Relative ) );
  var schema = XmlSchema.Read( resInfo.Stream, SchemaValidationCallBack );

  XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
  schemaSet.Add( schema );
  schemaSet.ValidationEventHandler += SchemaValidationCallBack;

  XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
  settings.Schemas = schemaSet;
  settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  using( XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create( xmlPath, settings ) ) {
    doc.Load( reader ); // <-- This line throws an exception if XML is ill-formed
    reader.Close();
  }
  doc.Validate( SchemaValidationCallBack );// <-- This is never reached
}

private void SchemaValidationCallBack( object sender, ValidationEventArgs e )
{
  Console.WriteLine( "SchemaValidationCallBack: " + e.Message );
}
```

How do I get the callback to be called so I can handle validation errors?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to handle the ValidationEventHandler envet of XmlReaderSettings class.

The XmlSchemaSet.ValidationEventHandler event will be fired if your XSD file is invalid.

The XmlReaderSettings.ValidationEventHandler event will be fired if your XML violates your XSD.